# Handling ZIP content in Java that uses the SHRINK algorithm

Tags: java, zip, shrink

Anyone know of a way to handle ZIP files produced using the SHRINK algorithm?  This doesn't appear to be supported by the standard Java ZIP functionality.

We're receiving ZIP files from an upstream system that (amazingly) have SHRINK-based compression in use.  This seems to be from an older mainframe-based ZIP encoder that can't be easily modified to use something more modern.

Comment: It looks like *Info Zip* supports this, so you could either look in [it's source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/UnZip%206.x%20(latest)/UnZip%206.0/) and port it to Java or call the program via command line. Only if we don't find a Java implementation, of course.

Comment: Porting over the shrink algorithm from somewhere wouldn't by itself solve the problem. Since the Java Zip libraries don't provide any way to hook in additional algorithms, I'd almost need to port the ENTIRE InfoZip library to have a working ZipInputStream that supported shrink. =(

Comment: Yes, that's right :-/. Java uses *zlib* internally, and this only supports `DEFLATE`, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of accepting an answer, it sounds like it's not possible to do directly in Java without porting code or building a JNI layer to hit native libraries that can handle this.